# Allow datagrid control to accept decimal values vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview, datagrid

Hi I have a datagrid control(not datagridview control) placed in a windows form(Vb) it have 10 columns. I am trying to input decimal value in one of the column but it is resetting its value. For ex:

I have 31 in a cell and trying to edit it to 20.5 as soon as i change the cell it resets back to 31. If i input any integer value like 21 it accepts the value.

```
_da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT EMPDETAILPERSONAL.EMPCODE, EMPDETAILPERSONAL.EMPNAME, EMPDETAILPERSONAL.EMPDEPT, EMPDETAILPERSONAL.EMPDOB, 0 AS AGE, " & _
    " EMPDETAILPERSONAL.EMPDOJ, EMPDETAILPERSONAL.EMPPANNP, " & Date.DaysInMonth(selYear, selMonth) & " AS NOD, " & Date.DaysInMonth(selYear, selMonth) & " AS LD, CSDEPT.CSDEPTNAME, EMPDETAILPERSONAL.EMPDESG, " & _
    " EMPDETAILPERSONAL.EMPSALACC, EMPDETAILPERSONAL.EMPPFACC, EMPDETAILPERSONAL.EMPPPFACC, EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPBASIC, EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPGPA, CDbl(0) AS CONS, " & _
    " EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPDA, EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPHRA, EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPTA, EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPMISCADD, EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPGRSAL, " & _
    " EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPPFMEM, EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPITAX, EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPMISCDED, EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPNETSAL, " & _
    " IIf(EMPLOAN.LOANAMTINST Is Null,0,EMPLOAN.LOANAMTINST) AS LOAN, CSDESIGNATION.CSDESGNAME, EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPINCDATE, EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPINCAPP, " & _
    " EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPBASIC AS o_basic, EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPGPA AS o_gpa, EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPDA AS o_da, " & _
    " EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPHRA AS o_hra, EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPTA AS o_ta, EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPPFMEM AS o_pf, EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPPFEMPL AS o_pf_e, " & _
    " EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPPPFEMPL AS o_ppf_e, EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPPFEMPL, EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPPPFEMPL, " & _
    " EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPMISCADD AS o_add, EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPITAX AS o_tax, EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPMISCDED AS o_less, " & _
    " IIf(EMPLOAN.LOANAMTINST Is Null,0,EMPLOAN.LOANAMTINST) AS o_loan, CDbl(0) AS EMPCONTRI,EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPCCA AS CCA,EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPMEDALL AS MEDALL,EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPOTHERALL AS OTHERALL,EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPESI AS ESI,EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPGPF AS GPF,EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPPAYSCALE AS PAYSCALE " & _
    " FROM EMPLOAN RIGHT JOIN (((EMPDETAILPERSONAL INNER JOIN CSDEPT ON EMPDETAILPERSONAL.EMPDEPT = CSDEPT.CSDEPTID) " & _
    " INNER JOIN EMPDETAILPAYROLL ON (EMPDETAILPERSONAL.EMPDESG = EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPDESG) AND (EMPDETAILPERSONAL.EMPDEPT = EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPDEPT) " & _
    " AND (EMPDETAILPERSONAL.EMPCODE = EMPDETAILPAYROLL.EMPCODE)) INNER JOIN CSDESIGNATION ON EMPDETAILPERSONAL.EMPDESG = CSDESIGNATION.CSDESGID) " & _
    " ON EMPLOAN.EMPCODE = EMPDETAILPERSONAL.EMPCODE " & _
    " WHERE EMPDETAILPERSONAL.EMPDOL Is Null ORDER BY IIF(EMPDETAILPERSONAL.EMPDESG = 1, '10','20') + EMPDETAILPERSONAL.EMPCODE", _con)
    _da.Fill(_dtEmp)

    dgEmp.DataSource = _dtEmp
```

There is nothing written in cellchanged event. Even value is resetting before triggering cellchanged event. Please help. Thanks

Comment: How EXACTLY is the grid configured and populated in the first place?

Comment: Also, why are you using a `DataGrid` instead of a `DataGridView`? The latter is better in almost all cases. The only advantage that I can think of for the `DataGrid` is being able to navigate multiple tables within the same grid.

Comment: It is populated using datatable at load event of form. It was an old project.

Comment: Is there an input filter on that column? For example, it only accepts digits, so no dots? Or possibly it accepts decimal numbers, but the language is not English? For example, the decimal point in French is comma `,` instead of dot `.`.

Comment: @RacilHilan No it does not have any filter and language is english. sample value 20.5

Comment: You need to post the code for your datagrid. We cannot help you with our eyes blindfolded.

Comment: @RacilHilan added the portion of code used to populate datagrid

Comment: No, I meant the code that creates the datagrid itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that the corresponding column of your `datatable` is not of an integer type. If the given column is some kind of `integer` this condition is then reflected in the `datagrid` column and when you enter values with decimals they are casted back to `integer`.

Comment: Already checked that. Database is in ms access and column is text type.

Comment: So you should have no problem entering something like `"asdfg"`. Is that right?

Comment: thanks a lot. I was missing the single quote from the query mentioned above in my question. Column name was LD.

Comment: Glad you could sort it out!

Comment: Marking this as an answer is deceiving to future readers. It does not answer your question as you clearly stated in your first comment. Your question must be closed because it was a simple typo (i.e. missing the apostrophe).

Comment: Well, this answer _does_ solve the fact that entering a number with decimal values into the grid is casted to an integer if the original column in the dataset is of integer type. That if you are concerned about the readers. If you are concerned about _how_ @DeepSharma solved his particular problem, that's another thing..

Comment: Yes, it solves a problem, but the OP didn't have that problem. So marking it as an answer is misleading, because it didn't solve the question's problem. The question turned out to be a simple typo and it will be closed at some point. But you're right about the fact that your answer can be useful to some readers by reminding them to check one possible source of issues. It is just not the answer to this question.

Comment: Question: _"Allow datagrid control to accept decimal values vb.net"_  Does the answer solve this kind of problem? _Yes!_ Did the author have another kind of problem that made him believe this was his problem? _Maybe_. Should this question be deleted? _No idea._